# How to upgrade MariaDB and MongoDB in a network-segregated environment

Tags: mongodb, server, mariadb, migration

**Background environment:**

1. MongoDB and MariaDB are in operation in a network separation environment.
2. It was decided to build a new server and upgrade the existing versions of MongoDB and MariaDB.
3. But we can't upgrade our own database and move database files because we're not connected to the network.
4. We decided to proceed by backing up the database and importing it into the versioned database.

**Questions:**

1. MariaDB knows that it guarantees compatibility from low to high versions (we need to see if there are any problems importing dump data). In the case of MongoDB, does this ensure compatibility?
2. Please let me know if there is a better way to back up and import using database dump files.

**Description**

If the server where the existing application is located is changed, there is a lot of experience in backing up and importing using the dump file for the database by using the same database version. It was confirmed that there was no problem with both mongodb and mariadb. However, we are not sure about version up.

Since we are mainly working on building solutions to other companies, it is difficult to try various things under certain circumstances. For this reason, the work is mainly carried out by referring to the official reference document and citing it. However, each database lacked an explanation of the network separation environment, leaving a question.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **MongoDB** you can in principle follow the normal [upgrade procedure](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/7.0-upgrade-standalone/).

The only difference is at

- Replace the 6.0 binaries with the 7.0 binaries.

In your case this step would be: Copy the backup files to the new serer and start `mongod` from the new server.

Ensure that you run only one version higher than your old version. If you need to upgrade more, then you have to run the upgrade in steps one-by-one:

Upgrade path: `4.0 -> 4.2 -> 4.4 -> 5.0 -> 6.0 -> 7.0`